# Main method is not static in class error

Tags: java, main-method

```
class useTent
{
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner (System.in);

    public void main (String[] args)
    {

        Tent t= new Tent();
        HireContract hc = new HireContract();
        ProcessHire(t, hc);
    }
}
```

this is my code, and i keep getting the same error:

> " Main method is not static in class useTent, please define the main method as:
>      public static void main(String[] args) "

and when i make the it static i get the following error:

> "C:\Users\Emma\Documents\opps ass1\useTent.java:22: error: non-static method 
>   ProcessHire(Tent,HireContract) cannot be referenced from a static context ProcessHire(t, hc);"

and also still the

> "Error: Main method is not static in class useTent, please define the main method as:
>      public static void main(String[] args)"

Comment: `public static void main (String... arguments)` and change the method signature of `ProcessHire(t,hc)` to static if possible

Comment: And please follow java naming conventions. `class UseTent`. `processHire()` if it indeed is a method as the error suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `main` requires `static` just like the error is telling you

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
```

And you didn't post `ProcessHire` but I think you wanted a `new` and perhaps to save the reference

```
ProcessHire ph = new ProcessHire(t, hc);
```

Comment: I thing `ProcessHire` is a method. In that case make it static to use it from main method.

Answer (score 1):

Java by default looks for a method

```
public static void main (String[] args) { }
```

or say

```
public static void main (String ...args) {}
```

args could be any name like 
    public static void main (String ...arguments) {}

If you already have a public static void main method then you can have another main method which would act as normal method.

Now when you make the method static you get the other error because in a static context, calling a non static method(local to class) without initializing it's object would give error as java don't allow non static calls from static context/methods.

```
 non-static method error
```

One example solution is make ProcessHire method static:-

```
class UseTent
{
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner (System.in);

public void main (String[] args)
    {

    Tent t= new Tent();
    HireContract hc = new HireContract();
    ProcessHire(t, hc);

    }

public static void processProcessHire(Tent tent,HireContract hireContract){
//your method definition
}
}
```

or if you can't make the method static then use approach below:-

```
class UseTent
{
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner (System.in);

public void main (String[] args)
    {

    Tent t= new Tent();
    HireContract hc = new HireContract();
   new UseTent().ProcessHire(t, hc);

    }

public void processProcessHire(Tent tent,HireContract hireContract){
//your method definition
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main class should be `public static void main (String[] args)`

Answer (score 0):

If ProcessHire method is static and in ABC class Try this,

```
class useTent{

    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner (System.in);

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Tent t= new Tent();
        HireContract hc = new HireContract();
        ABC.ProcessHire(t, hc);
   }
}
```

also follow Java Naming conventions.

Comment: hi, i tried your code and i get this error "C:\Users\Emma\Documents\opps ass1\useTent.java:21: error: non-static method ProcessHire(Tent,HireContract) cannot be referenced from a static context
        ProcessHire(t, hc);"